# How many zeros does this expression end in?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

How many zeroes does $$\frac{50!}{2^95^5}$$ end in?

Comment: Figure out the highest powers of 2 and 5 that divide 50!, and divide by $2^9*5^5$.

Comment: **Hint:** Count how many times $5$ appears as a factor of $50!$ and how many times $2$ appears as factor of $50!$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use the Lemma from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/590901), that says the number of factors of a prime $p$ that divide $n!$ is
$$
\frac{n-\sigma_p(n)}{p-1}
$$
where $\sigma_p(n)$ is the sum of the digits in the base-$p$ representation of $n$.

$50=110010_\text{two}$.

$50=200_\text{five}$.