# Exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

Exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n!$  is given by $\large  \sum \limits_{i=1}^{\lfloor\log_p n \rfloor } \left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor $.
Can this sum be simplified further to some direct expression so that the number of calculations are reduced?

Comment: This is an incredibly small calculation...

Comment: I am looking at @robjohn 's reply in below thread which shows that the sum simplifies to $\dfrac{n-\lfloor \log_p n\rfloor }{p-1}$ , but I don't really understand it and it is not giving correct answer for n=20 and p=2 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590885/proving-p-nmid-dbinomprmpr-where-p-nmid-m/590901#590901

Comment: robjohn's answer says that the sum simplifies to $\dfrac{n-\sigma_p(n)}{p-1}$, where $\sigma_p(n)$ is the sum of the digits of $n$ in the base-$p$ representation, just like David Holden's answer here. Where did you get the $\lfloor \log_p n\rfloor$ from?

Comment: @DanielFischer, he seems to have figured out about the digit sum... if $i > \log_p n$ then $p^i > n$ and the floor of the fraction is zero.

Comment: @WillJagy I was referring to the formula in the comment, not the bound on the sum. (Didn't even notice that there appeared a $\lfloor \log_p n\rfloor$ too.)

Comment: @DanielFischer, you are absolutely right. I did not notice the incorrect log in his comment...

Comment: FYI: There is an approximation for this found in Chapter 4 of Concrete Mathematics.  Only really useful for very large numbers, though.  (My book is packed up right now, and I don't know the exact formula off-hand.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes:

$$
\frac{N-\sigma_p(N)}{p-1}
$$
where $\sigma_p(N)$ is the sum of digits in the $p$-ary expression of $N$

Comment: I think $\sigma_p (N) $ is same as $\lfloor \log_p N\rfloor$ ? 

i am trying to work below example :
 exponent of 2 in prime factorization of $20!$ is $18$ :
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prime+factorization+of+20%21

but your expression gives a different number :
$\dfrac{20-\lfloor \log_2 20\rfloor }{2-1} = 16$

Comment: @GaneshTadi No. In binary, $20$ is $10100$, so the digit sum of $20$ in base-$2$ is $2$. $\frac{20-2}{2-1} = 18$, as it should be. $\lfloor \log_p n\rfloor$ is one less than the **number** of digits in base $p$.

Comment: if in binary $N=1101101$ then $\sigma_2(N) = 1+1+0+1+1+0+1=5$

Comment: Gotcha :) I see my error in interpreting the formula, thanks a lot xD

Answer (score 1):

note what Daniel says. $\lfloor \log_p N\rfloor$ is the exponent of $p$ in $N$ not in $N!$.
let $P_N$ be the exponent of $p$ in $N!$ and consider $P_{N+1}$.

if $N+1$ is not divisible by $p$ then the least significant $p$-ary digit of $N$ increases by $1$ and so 
$$
N+1 - \sigma_p(N+1) = N - \sigma_p(N)
$$
and the exponent is unchanged.

suppose $N+1$ is divisible by $p^r$ for $r \gt 0$ but not by $p^{r+1}$ then each of the $r$ least significant binary digits must take the value $p-1$ but $1$ is added to the $r^{\text{th}} $ digit, which is *not* equal to $p-1$ hence:
$$
\sigma_p(N+1) = \sigma_p(N)+1 - r(p-1)
$$
and
$$
N+1 - \sigma_p(N+1) = N - \sigma_p(n) + r(p-1)
$$
hence 
$$
P_{N+1} = \frac{N+1 - \sigma_p(N+1) }{p-1} \\
= P_N + r
$$

Answer (score 1):

The idea of this theorm is **to reduce  manual calculation** , try to find exp of 2 for (23263662!) :P so i guess its fair to follow the theorm  .
**Origion theorm  was**  $\large  \sum \limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor$ ,  the floor log n function come from condition that i<=n thus any i after n give term of zero.