# The exponent of $11$ in the prime factorization of $ 300!$ is___.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, exponentiation, factorial

> The exponent of $11$ in the prime factorization of $ 300!$ is

1. $27$
2. $28$
3. $29$
4. $30$

---

My attempt:

According to [Exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892215/exponent-of-p-in-the-prime-factorization-of-n)

$\left\lfloor\dfrac{300}{11}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\dfrac{300}{11^2}\right\rfloor=27+2=29$

> Can you explain in alternative/formal way? Please.

Comment: Do you mean to imply that the given method is not formal?

Comment: @Hagen Thanks. No, I'm agree with given explanation, but I'm looking to understand in other way, if there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the terms having factor $11$ are $11,22,33,..121,...220,..297$ so excluding $121,242$ we have $25$ numbers which give only one $11$ and $121,242$ gives two $11$ so total exponent is $11^{25}.11^4=11^{29}$

Comment: Yes, $121=11\times 11$ and $242=11\times 11\times 2$ will be include in exactly two times $11$, but other $25$ number included $11$ exactly once.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: You are welcome .

Comment: The general formula for the largest exponent of the prime $p$ in $n!$ is $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}[np^{-j}]$, where $ [x]$ denotes the largest integer not exceeding $x$. Note that only finitely many terms in the summation are non-zero. We can replace the supscript  "$ j=\infty$" with "$  j=n$".