# Confusion about the proof of If $n = 2^k - 1$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then every entry in row $n$ of pascal's triangle is odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I saw there were existing posts for this problem ([If $n = 2^k - 1$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then every entry in row $n$ of pascal's triangle is odd.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999328/if-n-2k-1-for-k-in-mathbbn-then-every-entry-in-row-n-of-pascals)), but I'm still confused. This problem is in the Book of Proofs, under the section of contrapositive proofs. What is a contrapositive or direct proof for this problem?