# Finding $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left(_nC_k \mod 2 \right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

How can I calculate the following expression?

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left(_nC_k \mod 2 \right)$$

To clarify my question, what I am asking is

$$\text{The number of odd coefficients in }(1+x)^n$$

Comment: Hint: $a \pmod{c} + b \pmod{c} = (a+b) \pmod{c}$ and $\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} = 2^n$

Comment: @Aritra I'm not asking $\left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} _nC_k \right) \mod 2 $, but asking $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left(_nC_k \mod 2\right) $ that can be greater than 1.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A001316

Comment: @KayK. Sorry, I thought you meant something else. I get it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/590901), $\binom{n}{k}\equiv1\pmod2$ precisely when adding $k$ and $n-k$ in base two incurs no carry; that is, $\sigma_2(n-k)+\sigma_2(k)=\sigma_2(n)$. That is precisely when $\operatorname{AND}(n,k)=k$, where $\operatorname{AND}$ is bitwise AND. Since $n$ has $\sigma_2(n)$ one bits in its binary representation, there are $2^{\sigma_2(n)}$ numbers $k$ so that $\operatorname{AND}(n,k)=k$; those numbers whose binary representation only has ones where $n$ has them.

---

For example, since $4=\color{#C00000}{1}00_{\text{two}}$,
$$
\{\color{#C00000}{0}00_{\text{two}}, \color{#C00000}{1}00_{\text{two}}\}=\{0,4\}
$$
is the set of $k$ so that $\binom{4}{k}$ is odd:
$$
(1+x)^4=x^{\color{#C00000}{0}}+4x^1+6x^2+4x^3+x^{\color{#C00000}{4}}
$$

---

For example, since $5=\color{#C00000}{1}0\color{#C00000}{1}_{\text{two}}$,
$$
\{\color{#C00000}{0}0\color{#C00000}{0}_{\text{two}}, \color{#C00000}{0}0\color{#C00000}{1}_{\text{two}}, \color{#C00000}{1}0\color{#C00000}{0}_{\text{two}}, \color{#C00000}{1}0\color{#C00000}{1}_{\text{two}}\}=\{0,1,4,5\}
$$
is the set of $k$ so that $\binom{5}{k}$ is odd:
$$
(1+x)^5=x^{\color{#C00000}{0}}+5x^{\color{#C00000}{1}}+10x^2+10x^3+5x^{\color{#C00000}{4}}+x^{\color{#C00000}{5}}
$$

---

For example, since $7=\color{#C00000}{111}_{\text{two}}$,
$$
\{\color{#C00000}{000}_{\text{two}}, \color{#C00000}{001}_{\text{two}}, \color{#C00000}{010}_{\text{two}}, \color{#C00000}{011}_{\text{two}}, \color{#C00000}{100}_{\text{two}}, \color{#C00000}{101}_{\text{two}}, \color{#C00000}{110}_{\text{two}}, \color{#C00000}{111}_{\text{two}}\}=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}
$$
is the set of $k$ so that $\binom{7}{k}$ is odd:
$$
(1+x)^7=x^{\color{#C00000}{0}}+7x^{\color{#C00000}{1}}+21x^{\color{#C00000}{2}}+35x^{\color{#C00000}{3}}+35x^{\color{#C00000}{4}}+21x^{\color{#C00000}{5}}+7x^{\color{#C00000}{6}}+x^{\color{#C00000}{7}}
$$

---

Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\bmod2=2^{\sigma_2(n)}
$$
where $\sigma_2(n)$ is the number of one bits in the binary representation of $n$.

Answer (score 2):

As in any other ring: calculate $\;(1+1)^n$ in $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$. Thee binomial formula is valid in any commutative ring.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following correctly, but wouldn't $\;(1+1)^n$ in $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ be only 0 or 1? But answer to my question can be greater than 1.

Comment: Oh! I see. You want to calculate the number of odd coefficients?

Comment: Yes, Bernard. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas'_theorem) is the key. The triangle of binomial coefficients $\!\!\pmod{2}$ looks like the [Sierpinski gasket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle) and the number of odd coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ with $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ can be computed through [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer's_theorem). Have a look also at [OEISA001316](https://oeis.org/A001316) - Gould's sequence. The number of odd coefficients is, in fact, 
$2$ raised to the power:

$$\nu_2\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)=\sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{2^k}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor\right).$$

Comment: Isn't $\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{2^k}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor$ just bit $k-1$ of the binary representation for $n$? In that case, I believe the actual number of odd coefficients is $2$ to the power you have computed above.

Comment: robjohn is right, I will fix this answer soon.