# ${2^k-1\choose a}$ is odd?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can I see that $${2^k-1\choose a}\equiv 1\mod 2$$
for $0<a<2^k$?

I tried playing around with ${2^k-1\choose a}=\frac{(2^k-1)!}{a!(2^k-1-a)!}$ but it didn't get me very far.

Comment: It is a duplicate and already has many answers. Please see whether [this helps you](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870782/prove-that-2n-1-choose-k-and-2n-k-choose-k-ar-always-odd?rq=1). Also see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317163/prove-if-n-2k-1-then-binomni-is-odd-for-0-leq-i-leq-n).

Answer (score 1):

Show that $\binom{2^k}{a}$ is even for $0<a<2^k$ which is equivalent to prove 
$$(1+x)^{2^k}\equiv 1+x^{2^k}\pmod{2}.$$
This can be seen by induction by noting that
$$(1+x)^{2^{k}}=(1+x)^{2^{k-1}}\cdot (1+x)^{2^{k-1}}
\equiv (1+x^{2^{k-1}})(1+x^{2^{k-1}})\\=1+2x^{2^{k-1}}+x^{2^{k}}\equiv
1+x^{2^k}\pmod{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the coefficient of $x^{a}$ in the expansion of
$$
(1 + x)^{2^{k} - 1}
$$
modulo $2$.

Now modulo $2$ one has
$$
(1 + x) (1 + x)^{2^{k} - 1}=
(1 + x)^{2^{k}} = 1 + x^{2^{k}} =
(1 + x)(1 + x + \dots + x^{2^{k} - 1}).
$$