# is $\sqrt[n]{n!}$ ever an integer?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial, radicals

> Does there exist an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ greater than $1$ such that $\sqrt[n]{n!}$ is an integer?

The expression seems to be increasing, so I was wondering if it is ever an integer. How could we prove that or what is the smallest value where it is an integer?

Comment: No (well, other than $n=1$).  By Bertrand, there is a prime $p$ between $\frac n2$ and $n$ and that prime can only divide $n!$ to the first power.

Answer (score 11):

This is impossible due to Bertrand's postulate, since there will always be a prime $ p $ in $ n! $ occuring with multiplicity $ 1 $ as long as $ n \geq 2 $. This actually implies that $ n! $ is never a perfect power for $ n \geq 2 $.

Answer (score 9):

If $\sqrt[n]{n!} = k \in \mathbb{N}$ then $n! = k^n$. When $n\geq 2$ we have $2\mid n!$ so we must also have $2\mid k$ which means that we can write $k = 2^{m} \ell$ for some integers $m$ and $\ell$. This again means that

$$n! = 2^{mn}\ell^n \implies 2^{mn} \mid n!$$

so the power of two that divides $n!$ is $mn$ which is greater or equal to $n$. On the other hand the power of two that divides $n!$ can be computed as

$$\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{8}\right\rfloor + \ldots$$

This expression is less than $\frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{4} + \frac{n}{8} +\ldots = n$ which gives us a contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

If $n\gt1$ then $\sqrt[n]{n!}$ is not an integer (so it is an irrational number). A [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930933/is-sqrtnn-ever-an-integer/1930938#1930938) using [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) has been posted. The proof of Bertrand's postulate is somewhat involved. Here is a proof without using Bertrand's postulate.

For a prime number $p,$ the $p$-adic order of a natural number $m,$ denoted by $\nu_p(m),$ is the highest exponent $\nu$ such that $p^\nu$ divides $m;$ the number $m$ is a perfect $k^\text{th}$ power if and only if $\nu_p(m)$ is divisible by $k$ for every prime $p.$ We can show that $n!$ is not a perfect $n^\text{th}$ power (for $n\gt1$) by showing that $\nu_2(n!)$ is not divisible by $n;$ in fact, $0\lt\nu_2(n!)\lt n.$ The lower bound is obvious. For the upper bound, let $m=\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor$ and use [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula):
$$\nu_2(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac n{2^k}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=1}^m\left\lfloor\frac n{2^k}\right\rfloor\le\sum_{k=1}^m\frac n{2^k}\lt\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac n{2^k}=n.$$

A much more general (and difficult) result, the Erdős-[Selfridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Selfridge) theorem, says that the product of two or more consecutive positive integers is never a perfect $k^\text{th}$ power for any $k\gt1.$

Answer (score 2):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/590901), it is shown that the number of factors of $p$ that divide $n!$ is
$$
\frac{n-\sigma_p(n)}{p-1}\tag{1}
$$
where $\sigma_p(n)$ is the sum of the base-$p$ digits of $n$.

For $n!$ be an $n^{\text{th}}$ power, $(1)$ must be a multiple of $n$ for any prime $p$.

For any $n\ge1$, we have $\sigma_p(n)\ge1$ for any prime $p$. Thus, $(1)$ is less than $n$, and since it must be a multiple of $n$, it must be $0$.

Thus, either $n=0$ or the number of factors of any prime $p$ that divides $n!$ must be $0$. Therefore, we either have $n=0$ or $n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is (for $n>2$) never an integer, since you always have a single prime number (meaning with exponent 1) and hence its $n$th root, namely the biggest prime smaller than $n$. Since the product of roots of different prime numbers are never integer, this number will never be an integer (for $n>2$).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The comment below by bof points out the flaw in my argument.
I am not deleting this answer. This proves a much weaker statement version that instead of "never happening"  this shows it cannot happen for two consecutive integers.

---

Bertrand's postulate  is the shortest  way to prove this as has been suggested in other answers/comments. Here is an alternative attempt.

Suppose $n!=x^n,$  and $(n+1)!=y^{n+1}$ for integers $x,y$. Then we get by dividing these two equations $$ n+1 =\bigg(\frac yx\bigg) ^n y  $$ As LHS is an integer so is the RHS. The only way  RHS can be an integer is $y/x$ be an integer (and   at least 2). That   means $n+1$ is bigger than $2^{n+1}$ (because y is at least 2). But this is absurd, giving the  required contradiction.

Comment: You get a contradiction from assuming that $n!$ is an $n^\text{th}$ power ***and*** $(n+1)!$ is an $(n+1)^\text{st}$ power? How does that prove that $n!$ is ***never*** a perfect $n^\text{th}$ power?

Comment: @bof: Your objection is valid. Let me think through this.