# A question about binomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Consider the following question.

> Let be $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Can one find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m$ divides $\binom{n}{k}$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n-1$?
>
> If not, does it hold for any particular $m \in \mathbb{N}$?

I actually do not know how to start.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067235/gcd-of-binomial-coefficients

Comment: A good find @lhf !

Comment: Filippo, your requirement implies that $m$ should divide that gcd. The linked thread says that the gcd is either a prime or $1$. You can conclude that this is possible if and only if ....

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you so much, now I see it!

Comment: Good! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, given that $m = 1,$ we have that $m$ divides $\binom n k$ for all integers $1 \leq k \leq n - 1.$

Given that $m$ is a prime, one can prove that $m$ divides $\binom n k$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n - 1$ so long as $n = m.$

**Proof.** Given that $m$ is prime and $n = m,$ we have that $$\binom m k = \frac{m!}{(m - k)! k!}$$ is an integer that is divisible by $m.$ Explicitly, the integers $(m - k)!$ and $k!$ do not divide $m$ by hypothesis that $m$ is prime and $1 \leq k \leq m - 1,$ hence we can factor out $m$ to obtain $$\binom m k = m \cdot \frac{(m - 1)!}{(m - k)! k!}.$$ But this says precisely that $m$ divides $\binom m k = \binom n k.$ QED.

Upon inpsection, if $m$ is prime, it seems that this could be true for the case that $n = m^i$ for some integer $i \geq 1.$ (Edit: [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen) has kindly directed my attention to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2067332/11619) from Andreas Caranti that confirms my hunch.) Beyond these few cases, I suspect that it is not true that $m$ divides $\binom n k$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n - 1,$ but again, I cannot confirm my suspicions with a proof.

Comment: If $p^j$ is the highest power of a prime $p$ that is a factor of $m$, then $p^{ji}$ is the highest power of $p$ that is a factor of $m^i$. [The answer by Andreas Caranti](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2067332/11619) explains that $p$ is not a factor of the binomial coefficient $\binom {m^i}{p^{ij}}$. This ruins it for $m^i$ unless $m=p^j$.

Comment: Yes, yes. That is what I meant. If $m$ is prime and $n$ is some power of $m,$ then I believe that $m$ divides $\binom n k.$

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Answer (score 1):

$$v_p\binom{n}{k}=v_p(n!)-v_p((n-k)!)-v_p(k!)$$
For $m|\binom{n}{k}$, we have $v_p(m)\le v_p\binom{n}{k}$ for all the prime divisors $p$ of $m$.

By legendre's formula, we have
$$v_p\binom{n}{k}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor
-\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n-k}{p^i}\right\rfloor+ \left\lfloor \frac{k}{p^i}\right\rfloor\right)\right)$$
Does that help?

Comment: How do you conclude? What is your claim? Could you please add more details?