# Reference request: gcd of binomial coefficients

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, gcd-and-lcm

Let $n > 1$. What is a good reference for the following fact?

$$\mathrm{gcd} \left\{\binom{n}{k} : 0 < k < n \right\} = \begin{cases} p & n = p^m \text{ is a prime power} \\ 1 & \text{else}\end{cases}$$

It has been discussed on math.SE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067235/gcd-of-binomial-coefficients). I am not looking for a proof, I am looking for a citable reference which also includes a proof. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06696.pdf) gives a reference to a paper from 1909 (B. Ram, *Common factors of n!/m!(n−m)!*) which I cannot access. So I am also looking for a reference which is easy to find. It does not have to be original. Ideally it would be a modern number theory textbook.

Comment: In a paper, citing a SE answer for a well-known result is bad practice.

Comment: A few articles you may try: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X85900137 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631073X16301054 https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.124.4.353

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I already did. See also the text in my question.

Comment: Not sure I understand: I read your question, and I understand there is an article you can't find. While looking for it I found these ones. But if you already found them and they are of no use, then I think I'm not able to help more. I may check in a couple of textbooks, but it's the kind of result I expect to find among exercises.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Is this it [*Common Factors*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101080760422&view=1up&seq=51)?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you for your mail!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg You're welcome. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to put this one off the unanswered list ...

> B. Ram, Common factors of n!/m!(n−m)!, J. Indian Math. Club (Madras) 1 (1909) 39-43

And thanks again @Jean-Claude Arbault for sending me the article!