# Binomial coefficient: Search for multiples of 13

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

*Question*:
**The coefficients of how many terms in the expansion of (1+x)<sup>2018</sup> are multiples of 13?**

So, we've to investigate the powers of 13 in ${2018 \choose r}$, where 0 ≤ r ≤ 2018

I tried using the following:
$$s_p(N!) = \left \lfloor \frac{N}{p} \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{N}{p^2} \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{N}{p^3} \right \rfloor + \cdots$$

where, $s_p(N!)$ denotes the highest exponent of prime p in n!, where n is a natural number.

${2018 \choose r}$, may be written as $\frac{2018!}{r!(2018-r)!}$. Now, I tried to figure out the exponent of 13 in numerator for several values of r, but couldn't find a pattern that would lead me to the desired answer.

Could someone please give a detailed solution to this problem, and also explain how to approach such problems? Is there any **generalisation for the multiples of a prime number p in ${n \choose r}$?**

P.S.
The answer, to the best of my recollection, is 1395.

Comment: It can generally be solved using Luca's theorem or the Kummer's theorem.  You can search on Google for more information about them

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Can we not solve it using the idea I proposed, though?

Comment: I do have another method . I will just post it as hint.  You try to figure out the underlying answer. OK?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Post it as an answer though. I'll try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*:

$$E_{13}(2018!)=\left \lfloor \frac {2018}{13}\right \rfloor+\left \lfloor \frac {2018}{13^2}\right \rfloor+\left \lfloor \frac {2018}{13^3}\right \rfloor \ldots $$
$$=155+11+0$$
$$=166$$

$$\Rightarrow E_{13}(r!)  +E_{13}((2018-r)!)\le 165$$
$$\Rightarrow r=13\lambda +k,      k=4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12$$

For $r=13\lambda+ 4$ we have following $155$ numbers 
$$r=4,17,30,....., 2006$$

And continue similarly for other values of $k$

$$\Rightarrow Total = 155*9=1395$$

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Sorry for the typo. And thanks , it is fixed now.

Comment: @schrodinger_16 its not just of the form 13m+4. it is of the the form 13m+k where k varies from 4 to 12. we get this condition when we solve the so formed inequality i gave. the general solution of the inequality was $$r\equiv 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 \pmod {13}$$

Comment: Great. Thanks, got it. This is the kind of the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Kummer's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem), as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/590901),

> The number of factors of $p$ in $\binom{n}{k}$ is  the number of carries in the addition $k+(n-k)=n$ when performed in base-$p$.

This means that the binomial coefficients $\binom{2018}{k}$ that are not divisible by $13$ are those where $k+(BC3_{13}-k)=BC3_{13}$ has no carries. That would be those with digits $0$-$B$ in the $13^2$ digit, $0$-$C$ in the $13^1$ digit, and $0$-$3$ in the $13^0$ digit. That is, there are $12\cdot13\cdot4=624$ coefficients which do not have a factor of $13$.

Thus, there are $2019-12\cdot13\cdot4=1395$ coefficients that have a factor of $13$.